# how to create loop in carousel with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, carousel

I wanna to create carousel like http://www.bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/media-slider-carousel-bs3 with java script and I dont know how to create loop?when the last picture is shown how will be shown the first picture ?for example I have 6 product

**HTML**

```
     <div id="slideshow">
       <div id="ruller">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="img/16X10Wallpaper_Persian-Star.org_16.jpg" />
            <span>product 1</span></a>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="img/16X10Wallpaper_Persian-Star.org_24.jpg" />
            <span>product 2</span></a>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="img/24ba51c7-d3e2-434a-9e1b-55f1b10d530b_6.jpg" />
            <span>product 3</span></a>
          </div> 
       </div>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    <script>
       a = 0;

     left_button.onclick = function () {
       a -= 225;
       ruller.style.left = a + 'px';
     }

     reight_button.onclick = function () {
       a += 225;
       ruller.style.left = a + 'px';
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use the javascript in the link provided. The example is using the carousel from Bootstrap (this also requires jQuery) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel. Are you asking about how to create the carousel effect yourself (without bootstrap)?

Comment: Yes I want to create without bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of the value of `a` and shift it accordingly. Here is an implemented example where you can use `% slideNum` to go from *last slide to the first slide*. Then from the *first slide to the last slide* you would do a check and set `a` to the last value.

In the example below I instead made `a` only increment by 1 and use a `move` variable which is `255`. Doing `a*move` will give the value you would use. This makes it easier to keep track of `a`:

```
a = 0;
var move = 255;
var slideNum = document.getElementsByClassName("item").length;

left_button.onclick = function () {
    a = (a - 1) % slideNum; // Move back a slide   
    if( a == -1 ) a = slideNum - 1; // If we move past the first slide, move to the last
    ruller.style.left = (a*move) + 'px';
    console.log(a*move); // Consoles the value we want 
}

right_button.onclick = function () {
    a = (a + 1) % slideNum; // Moves to the next slide, will move to the first when need due to %
    ruller.style.left = (a*move) + 'px';
    console.log(a*move); 
}
```

Since I don't have you pictures of the implemented carousel, I instead made the program simply give the correct data, being `(a*move)`.

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvb2L2xt/)